# showModal while tvOS native side grid layout is already displayed, and it crashes app

Tags: typescript, react-native, tvos

**Issue Description**

On tvOS, if a modal is opened up on top of a view which is already displayed, the app crashes with the following stack trace:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
> reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors
> <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x28248a840 "UIFocusGuide:0x2801f3ed0''.top"> and
> <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x28248a7c0 "RCTTVView:0x1051bda10.bottom">
> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its
> anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's
> illegal.'
>
> First throw call stack:
>
> (0x180c412c8 0x18047c114 0x1b7bfcc84 0x102cdc038 0x102cdb8e0 0x1c9a144c4 0x1c99ce0c8 0x1c9a14610 0x1c9a1432c 0x1c9a13a34
> 0x1c9a133a4 0x1c9a11258 0x1ca241fcc 0x1ca24241c 0x1c9e8acfc
> 0x1c9e7d318 0x1c9ea6764 0x180baa4b8 0x180ba4d70 0x180ba5268
> 0x180ba4a3c 0x18784ab0c 0x1c9e7e6ec 0x1c9e82bc4 0x102803580
> 0x1cd501744) libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type
> NSException

The real-world scenario in our case is that the app opens up a modal by selecting on a program, and at that point in time the app happen to be showing a grid view.

Environment
React Native version: 0.68.2-4
Platform(s) (Apple TV)
Device info (Simulator/Device? OS version? Debug/Release?): simulator or device, many different tvOS devices, tvOS 16.6

The expected result should be, the RN modal should show on top of all the component which is showing up on the Apple TV screen.